Proof of the Kunita-Watanabe inequality
I'm going to present a talk about the Kunita-Watanabe inequality, that is, for $X,Y$ measurable processes and $M,N$ local martingales we have
$$\int_0^t|X_sY_s|\,d|\langle M,N\rangle_s|
\leq\left(\int_0^tX_s^2\,d\langle M\rangle_s\right)^{1/2}\left(\int_0^tY_s^2\,d\langle N\rangle_s\right)^{1/2}\tag{$*$}$$
for all $0\leq t\leq\infty$ a.s.
It is clear to me that we can restrict our attention to $t<\infty$ and $X,Y$ bounded processes. Now this is where I run into difficulties. It's easy to verfiy that $(*)$ holds for simple processes of the form
$$
X_s(\omega)=\alpha_0(\omega)1_{\{0\}}(s)+\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i(\omega)1_{(t_{i-1},t_i]}(s),\quad
Y_s(\omega)=\beta_0(\omega)1_{\{0\}}(s)+\sum_{i=1}^n\beta_i(\omega)1_{(t_{i-1},t_i]}(s),
$$
where the $\alpha_i,\beta_i$ are bounded random variables and an increasing sequence $0=t_0\leq t_1\leq\dotsc\leq t_{n-1}\leq t_n$. But how do I generalize this for general bounded $X$ and $Y$? Revuz & Yor just states that this follows from density, but I've never heard before that simple processes of the above type are dense, especially w.r.t. pointwise convergence, in bounded processes. Another resource stated that we can use a functional monotone class argument, i.e. we show that say for fixed $Y$, the class of processes
$$
\mathcal{C}:=\{X:\mathbb{R}_+\times\Omega\to\mathbb{R}: X\text{ is bounded, measurable and satisfies } (*)\}
$$
contains simple processes and is closed under increasing limits. Then $(*)$ would follow for all bounded $X$. Analogously for $Y$. But again, it is not clear to me how to prove $(*)$ for $X$ simple, but $Y$ arbitrary. Moreover, as far as I can tell, $\mathcal{C}$ is not even a vectorspace, so I don't think we can apply monotone class anyway.
I've seen proofs that use different methods, but they generally need more working up to, e.g. in Karatzas & Shreve, and the talk is only 45 minutes, so I'd like to use as little machinery as possible.
So am I missing something here? Like, can we apply monotone class in a different form, or use a different approximation argument? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

The dominated Convergence Theorem  ensure the integrals converge appropriately due to uniform boundedness and pointwise convergence.

Thank you for your response. Yes that is true, but this only helps me, if I can indeed aprroximate X and Y by simple processes pointwise. What I'm asking is in part related to whether or not this is even possible.

Step 1: Proving the Inequality for Simple Measurable Processes
For simple measurable processes $ X $ and $ Y $, we can write:
$$
  X_s = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i 1_{A_i}(s), \quad Y_s = \sum_{j=1}^m \beta_j 1_{B_j}(s),
  $$
where $ \{A_i\}, \{B_j\} $ are measurable subsets of $ [0, t] \times \Omega $.
The integrals become finite sums:
$$
  \int_0^t |X_s Y_s| \, d|\langle M, N \rangle_s| = \sum_{i, j} |\alpha_i \beta_j| \int_{A_i \cap B_j} d|\langle M, N \rangle_s|.
  $$
Using properties of the quadratic covariation and applying the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we establish the inequality for these simple measurable processes.
Step 2: Extending to Arbitrary Bounded Measurable $ X $ (with $ Y $ Simple)
Approximation: For any bounded measurable process $ X $, we can find a sequence of simple measurable processes $ \{X^n\} $ such that $ X^n_s \to X_s $ pointwise for all $ s $ and $ |X^n_s| \leq K $ for some constant $ K $ (since $ X $ is bounded).

Applying the Dominated Convergence Theorem: Because $ |X^n_s Y_s| \leq K |Y_s| $ and $ Y $ is simple (hence bounded), we can apply the DCT to conclude:
$$
\int_0^t |X^n_s Y_s| \, d|\langle M, N \rangle_s| \to \int_0^t |X_s Y_s| \, d|\langle M, N \rangle_s|.
$$
Similarly for the other integrals involving $ X^n_s $.

Preservation of Inequality: Since the inequality holds for each $ X^n $, taking limits as $ n \to \infty $ preserves the inequality for $ X $.


Step 3: Extending to Arbitrary Bounded Measurable $ Y $
We repeat the same approximation argument for $ Y $ while keeping $ X $ fixed, using sequences of simple measurable processes $ \{Y^m\} $.
Applying the DCT again ensures the integrals converge, and the inequality holds in the limit.
Why Measurability Suffices?
Integration with Respect to Finite Variation Processes: The integrals in the Kunita-Watanabe inequality involve the quadratic variation processes $ \langle M \rangle $, $ \langle N \rangle $, and the covariation $ \langle M, N \rangle $, which are processes of finite variation. When integrating with respect to a finite variation process, the integrand only needs to be measurable (and adapted), not necessarily predictable.
Stochastic Integrals vs. Finite Variation Integrals: When integrating with respect to a local martingale $ M $ (i.e., $ \int X_s \, dM_s $), the integrand $ X $ must be predictable. However, for integrals like $ \int_0^t X_s \, d\langle M \rangle_s $, where $ \langle M \rangle $ is of finite variation, measurability suffices.

Thank you for elaborating. So if I'm understanding you correctly, in step 1 we show that the inequality holds for both $X$ and $Y$ simple processes. In step 2 we show that it holds for $X$ arbitrary and $Y$ simple, and the next step would be to then argue that we can also choose $Y$ arbitrary due to step 2. But you mention that $X$ has to be predictable. Why is that? In Revuz & Yor it only requires $X$ and $Y$ to be measurable.

Thank you for the edit, that helped. I have another question if you don't mind: In the book by Revuz & Yor, they use that we can find a density $J_s$ taking values in ${-1,1}$, such that $d\langle M,N\rangle=J_s|d\langle M,N\rangle|$. To me it is not at all obvious why that is the case, much less why such a $J_s$ would also be measurable. Do you have any idea?
